# Adding values of strings containing a specific string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an object called guild, that has the following array:

```
members: [
{
uuid: "6afc724d566746c796d13b233c9960ea",
rank: "MEMBER",
joined: 1492733608170,
dailyCoins-1-5-2017: 920,
dailyCoins-2-5-2017: 790,
dailyCoins-3-5-2017: 260,
dailyCoins-4-5-2017: 790
},
{
uuid: "fa014557f1ac4325b23940fb872031a4",
rank: "MEMBER",
joined: 1493332956351
},
etc.
```

How can I add together the value of each string that contains the string "dailyCoins" ?

Here is my current attempt:

```
 var guildMembers = [];
 var memberCoins = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < guild.members.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Object.keys(guild.members[i]).length; j++)
            console.log(Object.keys(guild.members[i]));
            if (Object.keys(guild.members[i])[j].includes("dailyCoins")) {
                var memberCoins = memberCoins + Object.values(guild.members[i])[j];
            }
        var member = {
            uuid: guild.members[i].uuid,
            rank: guild.members[i].rank,
            joined: guild.members[i].joined,
            coins: memberCoins
        };
        guildMembers.push(member);
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to change your starting object so that `dailyCoins` is an object itself structured like `{date:"1-5-2017",value:920}`?

Comment: The code should give a syntax error, wich is easy to resolve.

Comment: @George The object comes from an API, so doing it this way is the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should solve it in your way.

```
var guildMembers = [];
for (i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
  let memberCoins = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < Object.keys(members[i]).length; j++)
        if (Object.keys(members[i])[j].includes("dailyCoins")) {
             memberCoins = memberCoins + members[i][Object.keys(members[i])[j]];
        }
    var member = {
        uuid: members[i].uuid,
        rank: members[i].rank,
        joined: members[i].joined,
        coins: memberCoins
    };
    guildMembers.push(member);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinitializing memberCoins in loop?

Just change this line

```
var memberCoins = memberCoins + Object.values(guild.members[i])[j];
```

to

```
memberCoins += Object.values(guild.members[i])[j];
```

Complete Code

```
var guildMembers = [];
    var memberCoins = 0;
for (i = 0; i < guild.members.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Object.keys(guild.members[i]).length; j++) {
        console.log(Object.keys(guild.members[i]));

        if (Object.keys(guild.members[i])[j].includes("dailyCoins")) {
            memberCoins += Object.values(guild.members[i])[j];
        }
    }
var member = {
    uuid: guild.members[i].uuid,
        rank: guild.members[i].rank,
    joined: guild.members[i].joined,
    coins: memberCoins
};
guildMembers.push(member);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var members=guild.members.map(function(el){
  return {
        uuid: el.uuid,
        rank: el.rank,
        joined: el.joined,
        coins: Object.keys(el).filter(str=>str.includes("dailyCoins")).reduce((c,str)=>c+el[str],0)
    };      
});
```

You can simplify it using Array.filter / reduce...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` to iterate over your collection, `Object.keys(obj)` to fetch object properties, then `filter` to filter required object properties and `reduce` to accumulate result:

```js
var members  = [
  {
    'uuid': "6afc724d566746c796d13b233c9960ea",
    'rank': "MEMBER",
    'joined': 1492733608170,
    'dailyCoins-1-5-2017': 920,
    'dailyCoins-2-5-2017': 790,
    'dailyCoins-3-5-2017': 260,
    'dailyCoins-4-5-2017': 790
  },
  {
    'uuid': "fa014557f1ac4325b23940fb872031a4",
    'rank': "MEMBER",
    'joined': 1493332956351
  }
];

var guildMembers = members.map(function(row) { 
    var filter = function(key) { return key.indexOf('dailyCoins') >= 0; };        
    var reduce = function(sum, current) { return sum + row[current]; };
    
    return {
     uuid: row.uuid,
     rank: row.rank,
     joined: row.joined,
     coins: Object.keys(row).filter(filter).reduce(reduce, 0)
    };    
});

console.log(guildMembers);
```